# How to read histograms about variance from concurrency in practice?

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore, variance

In Java Concurency in Practice you can find following histogram(12.3):

[image]

The X axis(horizontal) has legend:

> per-thread completition time

.
and Y axis has legend

> Count of threads

In related text author explains about  *variance*. As I understand correct if I proceed a lot of experiments of executing same work and best result - 1 sec, the worst result - 5 sec, then variance -  4 sec.

Actually I cannot understand this histogram.

Quote from book:

> Figure 12.3 shows the perͲtask completion times of a variant of
>   TimedPutTakeTest using a buffer size of 1000 in which each of 256
>   concurrent tasks iterates only 1000 items for nonͲfair (shaded bars)
>   and fair semaphores (open bars). (Section 13.3 explains fair versus
>   nonͲfair queuing for locks and semaphores.) **Completion times for
>   non-fair semaphores range from 104 to 8,714 ms**, a factor of over
>   eighty. It is possible to reduce this range by forcing more fairness
>   in concurrency control; this is easy to do in BoundedBuffer by
>   initializing the semaphores to fair mode. As Figure 12.3 shows, this
>   succeeds in greatly reducing the variance (now ranging only from
>   38,194 to 38,207 ms), but unfortunately also greatly reduces the
>   throughput. (A longerͲrunning test with more typical kinds of tasks
>   would probably show an even larger throughput reduction.)

Can you explain where author find 104 and 8.714 numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

Variance is a notion from statistics which explains variability in data. So, from the chart it's clear that the non-fair semaphores have a wide range of completion times (=variance), and fair semaphores have small variance (so all the completion times are roughly the same).

Numbers 104 (0.1 second) and 8714 (8.7 seconds) are correspondingly leftmost and rightmost grey bars on your image.

So, the experiment was take a number of threads and execute a timing test against a fair and non-fair semaphores a number of times, plot total time / # of threads as a bar on a chart, then repeat the experiment with different number of threads.

Comment: can you explain why test conditions for fair and non-fair semaphore was dramatically different? in fair mode thread count was in range (~2)->(~40) but in fair ~70 and 200

Comment: Hmm I didn't tgink that 104 is same as 0.104 or at least .104 and this typo is absence here: http://jcip.net/errata.html

Comment: 104 ms = 0.104 seconds, your x axis is in seconds. As about why thread count was different for fair and non-fair semaphores I don't know. I would try actually running the test with different thread counts and plotting the chart for myself

Comment: **range from 104 to 8,714 ms**

Comment: yes, look at your chart. for non-fair semaphores. x axis is in **seconds**, it has ticks `0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10` **seconds** = `0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000` **ms**. First bar is between 0 and 2, close to 0 = that is 104ms the book talks about, the last one between 8 and 10, close to 8 = that is 8714ms the book talks about.